# How to exclude an array of id's from a find-method?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements, recommendation-engine, predictor-ruby-gem

I'm calling an array of recommended products (based on the `predictor-gem`) and want to exclude the products of the `current_user` from that set. I think that I'm using the proper condition for it `(" != ?")` but just not in the correct way. `@products_rec` should give that final array.

Here's the specific code in my `product_controller.rb`:

```
    recommender = ProductRecommender.new

    products = current_user.products

    @product_rec = (recommender.similarities_for("product-#{@product.id}")).map {|el| el.gsub(/(.*\-)[^\d]*/, "")}
    @products_rec = Product.find(@product_rec, :conditions => ["id != ?", products.id])
```

and here's my model, product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Reviewing
  include PublicActivity::Model
tracked

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

belongs_to :category

belongs_to :benefit

has_many :subscriptions
has_many :users, through: :subscriptions

has_many :benefits
has_many :projects, through: :benefits

belongs_to :user

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
validates :gtin, presence: false
validates :content, presence: false, length: { maximum: 2000 }
validates :video, presence: false
validates :tag, presence: false
validates :project, presence: false
validates :category, presence: false
validates :user, presence: false

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "680x300>", :thumb => "170x75>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

I want to exclude the products from the `current_user`, based on the users through subscriptions (see model).

How can I get this to work, any ideas?

**Final code:**
Based on the answer of `@Humza`, I've added the following working code to my `product_controller.rb`:

```
    recommender = ProductRecommender.new

    products = current_user.products.select("id")

    @product_rec = (recommender.similarities_for("product-#{@product.id}")).map {|el| el.gsub(/(.*\-)[^\d]*/, "")}
    @products_rec_array = Product.find(@product_rec)
    @products_rec = Product.where(id: @products_rec_array).where.not(id: products)
```

Comment: Which version of Rails you are using?

Comment: @Pavan any ideas on how I could solve this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find products with id not in array, you must do this:

```
array = current_user.products.pluck(:id)
Product.where('id NOT IN (?)', array) # '?' is surrounded by paranthesis
```

But since a product belongs to a user, you can simply do

```
Product.where('user_id != ?', current_user.id)
```

You can also use the `not` method like so:

```
Product.where.not(id: array)
Product.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)
```

**Edit:**

If you want the base products to be from some other list, this can help:

```
base_product_ids = some_list.map(&:id) # assuming this is an Array
Product.where(id: base_product_ids).where.not(user_id: current_user.id)
```

If `some_list` was an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you could have simply done:

```
some_list.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand it so far, but `@products_rec` needs to be based on `@product_rec` (that's an array of product id's coming from the `predictor-gem`), from which I want to detract product collection of `current_user`. And I don't know how to incorporate that within your code.

Comment: @SebastianPlasschaert, you want all products except those that belong to `current_user`, right? If yes, then look at how I'm getting the `array` variable.

Comment: it shouldn't be based on all products, but on the preselected set `@product_rec` (see `product_controller.rb`). I already tried `@product_rec.where()` but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Perfect, thanks: this did the trick! I added the final code to the description.